# Binding dropdown list selected item to model when outside form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have a website that is one page. It has anchors to navigate to different sections. The main page has 3 forms on it. At the top of the main page, outside of all forms, is a DropDownListFor() that I would like to bind to the model when submit is clicked on ANY form. This value in the drop down is relevant to all forms. As it stands now, the forms bind everything they need fine except for the selected value of the dropdown. Is there a way to grab that value for each form when a form is submitted so it can bind to the model? Everything that I find online talks about submitting the form with javascript but I am trying to just keep this in the cshtml file if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a hidden input to each form.
On each submit, call a function to grab the value of the drop down and populate the hidden input before submit.
Or alternatively, add an onchange event to the drop down to populate all 3 hidden inputs.